# Cannot connect to remote MSSQL from OSX Apache/PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, apache

I am building a site for a client that involves interacting with some of their internal databases running on SQL Server 2012. I am trying to get by dev environment up and running and trying to connect to a MSSQL 2012 Instance of SQLEXPRESS running on a Windows 7 VM running out of virtualbox. The VM has its own IP address and I can connect to it from my Mac using SQuirreL SQL with the JDBC Driver so I know the server is properly configured to allow remote connections.

However everything I do to try and connect through PHP on the Mac fails and it is starting to drive me round the bend!!

I am using ADODB to try and connect and have tried connecting with both the mssql and odbc_mssql drivers but it fails with an undisclosed error every time (I have tried enabling debug). This is my code:

```
$_dba = @NewADOConnection('myssql');
$_dba->debug = true;
$_dba->Connect('192.168.1.10', 'sa', 'password', 'database');
```

I have stepped through all the code with XDebug and it does not fail anywhere, all that happens is it calls mssql_connect which returns false.

I use the PHP installation from:

http://php-osx.liip.ch/

This includes the mssql module and the output of my php.ini is:

- MSSQL Support    enabled
- Active Persistent Links  0
- Active Links 0
- Library version  FreeTDS
- mssql.allow_persistent   On  On
- mssql.batchsize  0   0 mssql.charset UTF-8   UTF-8
- mssql.compatability_mode Off Off mssql.connect_timeout   5   5
- mssql.datetimeconvert    On  On mssql.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
- mssql.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited
- mssql.max_procs  Unlimited   Unlimited mssql.min_error_severity  10  10
- mssql.min_message_severity   10  10 mssql.secure_connection  Off Off
- mssql.textlimit  Server default  Server default mssql.textsize   Server
- default  Server default mssql.timeout    60  60

sql.safe_mode is also set to Off.

I have tested using 'tsql -H -p -U' which works as well as using 'tsql -S CON1' which also works, CON1 from my freetds.conf:

```
[CON1]
    host = 192.168.1.10
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

I am not sure if it makes a difference but FreeTDS was installed after PHP, I had to install it to get the config file to appear.

I have also tried simply testing with msyql_connect() with every possible combination of the connection details I can think of:

```
mssql_connect('192.168.1.10:1433', 'sa', 'password');
mssql_connect('\\\\192.168.1.10:1433', 'sa', 'password');
mssql_connect('\\\\192.168.1.10\\SQLEXPRESS:1433', 'sa', 'password');
mssql_connect('192.168.1.10', 'sa', 'password');
mssql_connect('\\\\192.168.1.10', 'sa', 'password');
mssql_connect('\\\\192.168.1.10\\SQLEXPRESS', 'sa', 'password');
```

And I am sure a few others that I have missed off of there too but none of them work either.

I am at a complete loss as to what to try next to be honest. I am hoping someone here might be able to provide me some more information.

Many thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I posted this I found where the issue is coming from, my PHP installation cannot find the FREETDS config file, to work around this I have set:

putenv('FREETDSCONF=/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf');

I need to find a more permanent work around for this (possibly just rebuild PHP) but it is working for now anyway.

Many thanks

Comment: This was part of my problem too. How or what decides which environment variables PHP sees (OS X, system apache, home-brew php)